# Count specific child nodes with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have lot of trouble with this XPath selction that i use in HtmlAgilityPack.

I want to select all `li` elements (if they exist) nested in another `li` witch have `a` tag with `id="menuItem2"`. 
This is html sample:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="menuItem1"></a></li>
    <li><a id="menuItem2"></a>
       <ul>
          <li><a id="menuSubItem1"></a></li>
          <li><a id="menuSubItem2"></a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>  
    <li><a id="menuItem3"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is XPath that i been using. When i lose this part `/ul/li`, it gets me the `a` tag that I wanted, but i need his descendants... This XPath always returns null.

```
string xpathExp = "//a[@id='" + parentIdHtml + "']/ul/li";
HtmlNodeCollection liNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpathExp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath should work.

```
string xpathExp = "//li/a[@id='" + parentIdHtml + "']/following-sibling::ul/li";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your xpath:

```
string xpathExp = "//li[a/@id='" + parentIdHtml + "']/ul/li";
```

The problem is that you were select the `a` node itself, which has no `ul` children. You need to select the `li` node first, and filter on its `a` child.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is so messy. You're using the HtmlAgilityPack, you might as well leverage the LINQ.

```
//find the li -- a *little* complicated with nested Where clauses, but clear enough.
HtmlNode li = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Where(n => n.ChildNodes.Where(a => a.Name.Equals("a") && a.Id.Equals("menuItem2", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0).FirstOrDefault();
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> liNodes = null;
if (li != null)
{
    //Node found, get all the descendent <li>
    liNodes = li.Descendants("li");
}
```

Comment: In this case, I'd say using LINQ here is much messier.  I find using XPath whenever available much nicer than writing out a LINQ query, especially when it's a complicated one.

Comment: You down-voted me because you think XPath is clearer thank Linq? And *particularly* when it's complicated? LOL...

Comment: I didn't downvote you... nor do I see a reason to do so.  It's a fine answer and I have no problem with it. I left that comment well before you got downvoted. Get your facts straight LOL...

Comment: Heh. I wish more people paid attention to the ettiquette of leaving a comment when downvoting. So confusing when they don't. And leaves innocent commenters open to frivolous accusations... :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description I think you want to select the two `<li>` elements that contain `<a>` tags with ids `menuSubItem1` and `menuSubItem2`?

If so then this is what you need

```
//li[a/@id="menuItem2"]//li
```